# Inherit ALL IEnumerator from base class

Tags: c#, oop

I'm really new to C#, so please be gentle on me ;)

I'm trying to write a class that will Inherit from the DataGridView Class.  For the most part, it's simple... but I'm running into issues when trying to access the base collections (DataGridViewRowCollection, etc...) using any of the linq queries... from what I understand... I'd need to implement the IEnumerable and IEnumerator interfaces... but I really have no additional functionality in that reguard, in my inherited class.  So... all I want is to make sure that my inherited class provides all the same query functionality as DataGridView does.

I've read quite a bit about this... but it seems I can't find a straight answer that will say "whatever... just implemented that stuff from the base class", programmatically.... of course...

Obviously, I'd like to have the users of my derived class (i.e. me) not have to bother with a bunch of explicit casts in the cases where the base class did not require them.

Finally... whatever I end up doing in my derived class... will I need to declare my class as:

MyDataGridViewClass : DataGridView, IEnumerable, IEnumerate

Or will the IEnumerable, IEnumerate parts be implicit once I fix what I have to fix in my code?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any implementation you do in a base class of any interface will be available on the inheritors (child classes).

```
interface IFoo
{
   void Foo();
}

class Foo : IFoo
{
   public void Foo() { }
}

class FooBar : Foo
{
}
```

This is all valid:

```
FooBar fooBar = new FooBar();
Foo foo = fooBar;
IFoo ifoo = foo;

ifoo.Foo();
```

If the `Foo` method is declared explicitly:

```
class Foo : IFoo
{
   void IFoo.Foo() { }
}
```

a cast will have to happen.

Comment: You gotta be f@$% s$%^& me...  I have been spending about 1 day and a half on this... only to find out I was only missing the:
"using System.Linq"
in my file.  When I was doing the same tests on the base class, I was in a different file which already included that statement... 
Thanks Daniel for taking the time… That’s how I understood things to work… just wasn’t working for me because of that little tiny thing… When you don’t know exactly what you’re doing, that stuff happens I guess… the compiler/intellisense wasn’t helping me out too much with its unrelated messages.